# VirtualHost allow both www and non-www

Tags: apache

Let's say I'm using both `www.example` and `example.com` URL's. If my VirtualHost directory is setup to accept `example.com` only, which means anyone using `www.example.com` won't be able to access the website.

I want anyone using `www.example.com` or `example.com` to reach to my website. How can I solve this?

```
LogFormat "%h^__%v^_%V^_%l^_%u^_%t^_%r^_%>s^%b^_%{Referer}i^%{User-Agent}i" vhost

NameVirtualHost *:80

<Directory *>
    Options FollowSymLinks ExecCGI Includes MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    AcceptPathInfo On
</Directory>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/%0/html
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use both a `ServerName` and a `ServerAlias`

Here is what I use for my templates -

For non-SSL -

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName example.com
  ServerAlias www.example.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www-example.com
    <directory /var/www-example.com>
        Options All
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </directory>
  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/example.com-error.log
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/example.com-access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

And with SSL from LetsEncrypt -

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName example.com
  ServerAlias www.example.com
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost 10.0.2.5:443>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem
    SetEnvIf User-Agent ".*MSIE.*" nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/ssl_request_log "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"
    DocumentRoot /var/www-example.com
    <directory /var/www-example.com>
        Options All
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </directory>
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/ssl-example.com-error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/ssl-example.com-access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```